# The relation between double loops and number of operations

Tags: algorithm

My teacher told me that basically whenever we had a loop and a nested loop the number of operation was as follows n(n+1)/2.

However, I looked at some programs and I realized that it's unlikely to be the case.

```
for(i=0, i<n, n++)
 for(j=i, j<n, j++)
 {x=i+j}
```

in this case it would be n(n+1)/2, ignoring i=0, j=0, n++, j++ and x=i+j, but here:

```
for(i=0, i<n, n++)
 for(j=0, j<n, j++)
 {x=i+j}
```

it would be n^n unless i am mistaken.

Can someone tell me exactly when two loops have n(n+1)/2 number of operations? I am kinda confused right now.

Comment: Your teacher made a hasty generalization. The run time of two nested loops can be virtually anything.

Comment: Wow, that escalated quickly! I think you mean n^2, not n^n.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, the operation would be done `n` times, then `n-1` times, then `n-2` times. If I remember correctly, this is `n(n-1)/2`, but you could be right and it's `n(n+1)/2`. Either way, it's a very small difference.

In your second example, it would be done `n` times, then `n` times, then `n` times... until you've done it `n` times `n` times -- in other words, `n^2`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably misunderstood the teacher (or the teacher made a mistake). `n(n-1)/2` is just one example of a common loop runtime. It can be anything as you've observed. Your second example has `n^2` operations though, another common pattern. 'n^n' is much rarer.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0, i<n, n++)
 for(j=0, j<n, j++)
 {x=i+j}
```

First loop runs `n` times and for each iteration you run second loop `n` times, thus you have `n*n = n^2`.

```
for(i=0, i<n, n++)
 for(j=i, j<n, j++)
 {x=i+j}
```

First loop runs `n` times and for each iteration you run the second loop `(n-i)` times....thus number of times `x=i+j` is getting executed is `1 + 2 + 3 ..... + n` times, this sequence is sum of first `n` integers, which is same as  `n(n+1)/2`